# Asp.net MVC2 Deployment: Directory Listing Denied

Tags: asp.net-mvc, deployment, iis-6

I have created an Asp.net MVC2 application in VS2008. When I am running the website on internal server its working fine. But when I created a virtual directory for the website on local IIS6, it's giving me error

> Directory Listing Denied
>
> This Virtual Directory does not allow contents to be listed.

How can I deploy the asp.net MVC site on local IIS6?

Comment: An answer below is link-only, and may be deleted by the Review Queue. It was accepted, [so I will copy it here](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx).